# Flutter sample build issue

Tags: flutter

I am getting this error when trying to run the sample first_app in flutter after opening it in VS CODE.

```
=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/ts/Documents/Dev/first_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar
    detritus not allowed
    Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: Please add your output to `flutter doctor` command

Comment: I fixed this with the Flutter Clean command.

Comment: Thank you @ToddS! You should add this as your own answer and accept.